# I'm developing a cordova Bluemix push notification application. I'm not able to find "applicationSecret" when I create from the Bluemix dashboard

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I'm developing a cordova Bluemix push notification application.

I'm not able to find "applicationSecret" when I create from the Bluemix dashboard.

```
bluemixpush: function() {
  console.log("device is ready, let's initialize bluemix!");
  var values = {
    applicationId: "",
    applicationSecret: "<INSERT_APPLICATION_SECRET_HERE>",
    applicationRoute: ""
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application secret is in the Mobile Application Security Dashboard which can be found from the navigation menu to the left in your application dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks James. But now i guess im not able to register the device for push notification on android.